# Hibernate extracts value in wrong data type

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have 2 entities Brand and BrandMerchantDefinition below. In the ACQ_BRAND table's brand_code column, I have data like 00021,00022 etc (mostly starts with zero).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACQ_BRAND", schema = "ACQ")
public class BrandEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_ACQ_BRAND", sequenceName = "SEQ_ACQ_BRAND", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_ACQ_BRAND")
    private Long id;
    @Version
    private Long version;
    private String corporationCode;
    private String brandCode;
    private String brandDescription;
    private String status;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "brandCode", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<BrandMerchantDefinitionEntity> brandMerchantDefinitionEntities;
}
```

They are joined on brand_code column.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACQ_BRAND_MERCHANT_DEFINITION", schema = "ACQ")

public class BrandMerchantDefinitionEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_ACQ_BRAND_MERCHANT_DEFINITION")
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "SEQ_ACQ_BRAND_MERCHANT_DEFINITION", name = "SEQ_ACQ_BRAND_MERCHANT_DEFINITION", allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;

@Version
@Column(name = "VERSION")
private Long version;

@Column(name = "STATUS")
private String status;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = BrandEntity.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "BRAND_CODE", insertable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition= "VARCHAR2(10)")
private BrandEntity brandCode;

@Column(name = "STORE_CODE")
private String storeCode;

@Column(name = "CITY_NAME")
private String cityName;

}
```

I am trying to find an entity with `brand_code = '00046'`. The problem is, even though the brand_code column is defined as `String`, (and `varchar2(10)` in the database) the hibernate extracts it as `BIGINT`.

Here are the generated sql:

```
    Hibernate: 
    /* dynamic native SQL query */ select
        a.* 
    from
        acq_brand_merchant_definition a,
        acq_brand b 
    where
        a.brand_code = b.brand_code 
        and a.brand_code =?
2018-12-04 18:39:15.940 TRACE 1640 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [00046]
2018-12-04 18:39:16.140 TRACE 1640 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id] : [BIGINT]) - [2]
2018-12-04 18:39:16.285 TRACE 1640 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([address] : [VARCHAR]) - [Adres]
2018-12-04 18:39:16.293 TRACE 1640 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([brand_code] : [BIGINT]) - [46]
2018-12-04 18:39:16.299 TRACE 1640 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([city_name] : [VARCHAR]) - [55]
```

What's interesting is, city_name is another column with `VARCHAR2` that holds numerical number. But it does not contain zeros at the beginning and it is extracted as `VARCHAR`.

How can I force Hibernate to extract `VARCHAR2` value as `String`?

Comment: You have JoinColumn with BRAND_CODE but the primary key of BrandEntity is a Long. Why?

Comment: `@JoinColumn(name = "BRAND_CODE")` means that the `ACQ_BRAND_MERCHANT_DEFINITION` table must have a `BRAND_CODE` column. By default, `@JoinColumn`s map to the primary key of the referenced table (`ACQ_BRAND` in this case). Since the primary key for the referenced table is a number, the foreign key in the referencing table is also a number. Since you want the foreign key to refer to a column that is not the primary key in the referenced table, you must provide this information to the JPA provider. `@JoinColumn(name = "BRAND_CODE", referencedColumnName = "BRAND_CODE")` will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The join column references the primary key, i.e. the id column of the entity. That is specified as `Long` therefore `BIGINT` sounds like a reasonable choice.

If you want to be handled as `String`/`VARCHAR` you need to change the primary key attribute to `String`.